# Microsoft SQL query multiple condition

Tags: sql, performance

I have an Attributes table which has a set of attributes identified by a unique number and then followed by their description - An example schema is

```
ID - AttributeName
```

with some sample data below

```
1 = FirstName
2 = LastName
3 = Phone
```

I then have an employees table which for the sake of simplicity has the following schema

```
ID - PersonID
AttribueID - INT Foreign key to the above attributes table
```

I need to create a stored proc that given a condition will return records based on one of the following conditions

If I pass in a 1 to the stored procedure the proc should return all records from the Person table who match the attribute ID 1 (First name)
If I pass in a 2 to the stored procedure the proc should return all records from the Person table who * DO NOT * match the attribute ID 1 (First name)
If I pass in a 3 to the stored procedure the proc should return all records from the Person table

I could do the following but feel it is not the best way this could be performed

```
DECLARE @IntID INT = 1 -- Set as 1 just for exmple

IF @IntID =1
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM Person where AttributeID IN (SELECT ID from Attributes Where ID =1) -- match on attribute 1
END
ELSE IF @IntID = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Person where AttributeID NOT IN (SELECT ID from Attributes Where ID =1) -- do not match on attribute 1

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Person where AttributeID IN (SELECT ID from Attributes) -- return match on all attributes
END
```

The above example has an extremely simple SELECT statement - in the real SQL there is a much larger set

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't wanna use dynamic sql then you may try this. And your query is too simple that for performance optimization, you may look to the table indexes for that.

```
DECLARE @IntID INT = 1 -- Set as 1 just for exmple

IF @IntID = 1 OR @IntID = 2
BEGIN

    SELECT A.* 
    FROM Person A
    LEFT JOIN Attributes B ON A.AttributeID = B.ID AND B.ID = 1
    WHERE 
    A.AttributeID IS CASE @IntID WHEN 1 THEN NOT NULL WHEN 2 THEN NULL END 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT A.* 
    FROM Person A
    INNER JOIN Attributes B ON A.AttributeID = B.ID
END
```

Comment: Combining multiple cases into single universal select can cause suboptimal execution plan, I would generally recommend to avoid that.